# Can I use "gf" (or similar) to open a file and jump to a search term?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, search

Is there a way to get vim's `gf` command (or something similar) to recognize a `+{cmd}` argument for file-paths?

One can start vim and go directly to a search term by doing:

```
$ vim +/coding_effort ~/project/file
```

Similarly, in command mode you can do:

```
:e +/coding_effort ~/project/file
```

I often take notes and refer to other files like this:

```
For more info see +/coding_effort ~/project/file where there's a detailed discussion.
```

I'd love to be able to select `+/coding_effort ~/project/file`, type something like `gf`, and have vim do the right thing.

Comment: I don't think there is any way of doing this by default, but you could probably create a plugin which does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the first problem is that the necessary space between command and filename is not part of the '`isfname'` option, and adding it would mean file borders couldn't be recognized at all. You'd either have to always use a visual selection (of both command and filename), or implement custom parsing in a `gf` command overload.

Secondly, the built-in `gf` doesn't recognize the `+{cmd}` syntax, so there's really no way around implementing your own custom mapping. This is certainly possible (using functions like `expand('<cfile>')`, `getline()`, etc.), but probably takes a few lines of Vimscript function.

If you choose a different syntax (`filename:+command`), you can keep the original `gf` commands and implement the splitting in an `:autocmd`, similar to what the very related [file:line](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2184) plugin does for `filespec:linenumber`).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function which should replicate the built-in `gf` behaviour, and *also* scans for works starting with `+` which then gets passed to `:edit`

```
fun! GotoWithCommand()
        let l:file = expand('<cfile>')

        " Replace ~ with the home directory
        let l:file = substitute(l:file, '^\~', $HOME, '')

        " File doesn't exist; return
        if !filereadable(l:file)
                echohl ErrorMsg
                echomsg "E447: Can't find file \"" . l:file . '" in path'
                echohl None
                return 0
        endif

        " Save cursor postion
        let l:save_cursor = getpos(".")

        " Make sure we go to the previous word (B on the first character of the
        " filename goes to the previous word, B anywhere else goes to the start of
        " the filename)
        call search('\(\s\|^\)', 'b')

        " Try to find argument to be executed; these start with a `+'
        let l:commands = ''
        while 1
                " Go one WORD backwards
                normal! B

                " Not a +; stop the loop
                if getline('.')[col('.') - 1] != '+'
                        break
                endif

                let l:commands .= ' ' . expand('<cWORD>')
        endwhile

        " Restore cursor postion
        call setpos('.', l:save_cursor)

        " Now, open the new file...
        execute ':edit ' . l:commands . ' ' . l:file
endfun

nnoremap <Leader>gf :call GotoWithCommand()<CR>
```

The comments should explain what the function does in more detail ... I wrote this on the train the morning, and (obviously) didn't test it extensively ;-)

Answer (score 2):

One option would be (assuming the `+cmd file/path` is selected) to yank the selection to a register, then insert that register in the command prompt. I did this with the following mapping:

`vnoremap gsf "0y:e <c-r>0<cr>`

Answer (score 2):

This notation works (`file name` + `trailing :` + `/ pat /`)

```
/usr/include/stdio.h:/int printf/  -- `file name` + `:` + `/ pat /`
/usr/include/stdio.h:+/int printf/
/usr/include/stdio.h: /int printf/
/usr/include/stdio.h: /#define\s/
/usr/include/stdio.h: /^#define\sSEEK/
```

with function and mapping below.

```
nn gf :<C-u>call Gf_search()<CR>

func! Gf_search() abort
    let word = expand('<cWORD>')
    let idx = stridx(word, ':')
    if idx != -1
        let remline = strpart(getline('.'),col('.'))
        let pat = substitute(remline, '.*[:+ ]/\([^/]*\)/.*', '\1', "")
        if pat != remline
            let pat = substitute(pat, '\\', '\\\\', 'g')
            let pat = substitute(pat, ' ', '\\ ', 'g')
            let filename = expand('<cfile>')
            exec 'e +/'.pat filename
            return
        endif
    endif
    " fallback to builtin gF
    norm! gF
endfunc
```